# How do I load a previous non-dedicated multiplayer session in ARK?

Tags: windows, ark-survival-evolved

ARK has a non-dedicated multiplayer session, which allows you to host a server and play at the same time, along with a friend. When you start one of these sessions, and then 'quit', it never asks you to save. After quitting, how do you restore the non-dedicated multiplayer session again, with the progress you made during the previous session? I can't find a load button or anything like that. I am asking specifically for the Windows platform.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simply choosing to host a Non-Dedicated Server again on the same map (The Ark, Scorched Earth, or The Center) will load up the same world. It is worth noting that the Non-Dedicated Server world is the same as Single Player world for the host. Note that the same player has to host each time.